# ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111:file_put_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm  creating an API and there on making a request I got this. error

`ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111:
file_put_contents(/opt/lampp/htdocs/Baller/storage/framework/cache/data/ce/3c/ce3cca4e3f5b66351ec8b603994311ed663c5c5f): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I've looked into my code but found nothing in it also I've cleared the cache as suggested in the related questions but nothing has worked for me till now can you people help me in tracing this error?

ScheduleController.php

```
public function addSchedule(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'homeCourtId' => $request->homeCourtId,
            'timeFrom' => $request->timeFrom,
            'duration' => $request->duration,
        ),
        array(
            'homeCourtId' => 'required',
            'timeFrom' => 'required',
            'duration' => 'required',
        )
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        if ($errors->first('homeCourtId')) {
            $message = $errors->first('homeCourtId');
        } else if ($errors->first('timeFrom')) {
            $message = $errors->first('timeFrom');
        } else if ($errors->first('duration')) {
            $message = $errors->first('duration');
        } else {
            $message = Constant::MSG_422;
        }
        $this->setMeta("422", $message);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $timeFrom= $request->timeFrom;
    $getDuration = $request->duration;
    $duration= 360*$getDuration;
    $timeTo = $timeFrom+$duration;
    $userHomeCourtId= UserHomeCourt::where(array('userId'=> $request->userId,'homeCourtId'=> $request->homeCourtId, 'userHomeCourtStatus'=>Constant::STATUS_1))->pluck('userHomeCourtId');
    if(!$userHomeCourtId) {
        $this->setMeta('403', __('apiMessages.invalidHomeCourtId'));
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    try {
        $schedule = new Schedule();
        $schedule->userHomeCourtId = $userHomeCourtId;
        $schedule->timeFrom = $request->timeFrom;
        $schedule->timeTo = $timeTo;
        $schedule->duration = $duration;
        $schedule->save();
        $this->setMeta('200', 'Schedule has been successfully set');
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        $this->setMeta('500', Constant::MSG_500);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
}

// get schedule
public function fetchSchedule(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'homeCourtId' => $request->homeCourtId,
            'currentTime' => $request->currentTime,
        ),
        array(
            'homeCourtId' => 'required',
            'currentTime' => 'required',
        )
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        if ($errors->first('homeCourtId')) {
            $message = $errors->first('homeCourtId');
        } else if ($errors->first('currentTime')) {
            $message = $errors->first('currentTime');
        } else {
            $message = Constant::MSG_422;
        }
        $this->setMeta("422", $message);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $userHomeCourtId= UserHomeCourt::where(array('userId'=> $request->userId,'homeCourtId'=> $request->homeCourtId, 'userHomeCourtStatus'=>Constant::STATUS_1))->pluck('userHomeCourtId');
    if(!$userHomeCourtId) {
        $this->setMeta('403', __('apiMessages.invalidHomeCourtId'));
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $fetchSchedule=Schedule::where('userHomeCourtId','=',$userHomeCourtId)->get();
    if(!$fetchSchedule) {
        $this->setMeta('200', __('apiMessages.noSchedule'));
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    $this->setMeta('200', __('apiMessages.scheduleList'));
    $this->setData('scheduleUsers', $fetchSchedule);
    return response()->json($this->setResponse());

}
```

Routes

api.php

```
Route::post('/addSchedule','Api\ScheduleController@addSchedule');
Route::post('/fetchSchedule','Api\ScheduleController@fetchSchedule');
```

Comment: `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: delete all views from `storage/framework/views` page first

Comment: still the same thing.

Comment: try adding `dd();` at first line in your `addSchedule` and check

Comment: well got this it's about permission of cache directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well it's just a matter of permission all I need to give permission to cache directory using sudo command

```
$ sudo chmod 777 -R .
```

that's it

Comment: Yeah, and this need to be done in `storage/framework` folder. I did it there and it's working. Just in case for newbies, to prevent `chmod 777` on root of application.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer helped me a lot. The following worked for me.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R storage/

sudo chmod 777 -R bootstrap/
```